# Do conservation oriented genetic database exist?

Tags: genetics, ecology, database, conservation-biology

Are there any projects for the creation of the international genetic database of all endangered species, so we, at least, have a chance to clone them in the future if our current conservational efforts fail?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I assume you meant conservation rather than conversation? Please take the time to go through the [tour] and then the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

First, it isn't entirely clear to me why you would want such a database.  Essentially all sequences are available in one (typically all) of the big databases.

For example if I search the NCBI database for "extinct" I get [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=extinct).  There will be many more sequences for species that are "only" endangered.

Second, having a genome sequence isn't sufficient for "[de-extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-extinction)" of a species.  The reasons for this are beyond the scope of this question, but can be explored starting from [this section of the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-extinction#Arguments_against_de-extinction).

You will likely also find [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/is-there-an-initiative-to-sequence-the-genomes-of-critically-endangered-species) discussion to be of interest.